# File Explorer crashes

Tags: windows-explorer, crash, windows-8.1-preview

I`ve been having this silly problem since update, my File Explorer crashes  whenever I try to use it. If I run app from taskbar (or Start menu, doesn't matter), the taskbar goes blank for a second or two, and nothing opens.

On the other side, if I select start with my right mouse button and open file directory,it works without flaw!

Do you know what may be the cause if this error? It all started happening since 8.1 update.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a problem with DLNA. You can disable the DLNA Shell Extension to prevent this from happening. Copy and past the following information into a text file and save it as a .reg file (.e.g “import.reg”). Then import it into your registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked] "{289AF617-1CC3-42A6-926C-E6A863F0E3BA}"=""
```

Restart Explorer.exe or your machine afterwards. [Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/home_is_where_i_lay_my_head/archive/2013/06/30/windows-8-1-preview-explorer-exe-crashes.aspx)

Comment: This did not work for me.